# How to deep copy (clone) an object with array members in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, clone, deep-copy

### Introduction

I have a Class `Persons` that contains an array of `Person` and functions :

```
function Persons() {
  this.mItems = []; // Array of Objects Person
}

Persons.prototype = {
  calculateScores : function() {
    // Do some stuff
  }
}
```

The Class `Person` has members and functions :

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name; // Name of the Person
  this.score = 0;
}

Person.prototype = {
  calculateScore : function() {
    // Do some stuff
  }
}
```

I want that the program does the following things :

```
var persons = new Persons();
var person0 = new Person("John");
var person1 = new Person("Sam");
persons.mItems.push(person0);
persons.mItems.push(person1);

// Completely clone the original Objects
clonedPersons = persons.clone(); // I am looking for a clone() function

// Modify an item in the cloned Objects
clonedPersons.mItems[0].name = "Mick";

// Check that the original Objects have not been modified
console.log(persons.mItems[0].name); // John : Not modified
console.log(clonedPersons.mItems[0].name); // Mick
```

### Question

**I want to deep copy an instance of `Persons`** to completely duplicate the Array of `Person`. The Objects Person must be duplicated. The functions of the Objects must be kept.

### JQuery.extend()

`JQuery.extend(true, {}, persons)` clones the direct members of `Persons` but shallow copies the `Person` Objects.

```
console.log(persons.mItems[0].name); // Mick : Where is John ?!
console.log(clonedPersons.mItems[0].name); // Mick
```

### JSON.parse(json.stringify())

`clonedPersons = JSON.parse(json.stringify(persons))` clones the Objects but remove the functions.

```
persons.mItems[0].calculateScore(); // Does not exists !!!
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: Yes, but `var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);` does not deep copies the objects in the Array.

Comment: You're not asking about how to clone objects that contain arrays, but about how to clone class instances.

Comment: @Bergi : Is it not the same ? Objects are Class instances ?

Comment: @Samuel: Usually we distinguish "plain" objects and arrays, which both are native "data types", from objects with custom prototypes that are created from user-defined constructors ("classes"). As you have seen, most deep-clone function support the former but not the latter.

Comment: @Bergi : OK I understand my misunderstanding. I mingled native objects and user-defined objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're dealing with custom classes, you're going to want to implement custom `clone` methods. Generally, in this context, I'd have 2 separate `clone` functions, one on the `Person` model and one on the `Persons` collection.

```
Persons.prototype = {
  clone: function() {
    var clone = new Persons();
    clone.mItems = this.mItems.map(function(person) {
        return person.clone();
    });
    return clone;
  }
}

Person.prototype = {
  clone: function() {
    var clone = new Person(this.name);
    clone.score = this.score;
    return clone;
  }
}
```

The advantage to this approach is that it separates the concerns - the `Person` class doesn't have to know how to clone a single `Person`, it only has to know that `Person` exposes a `clone` method. If `Person` adds a new property that should be persisted in the clone, only `Person` needs to change.

It's generally an anti-pattern to use generic `clone` methods, e.g. from jQuery or Underscore, in this context. They'll end up cloning things you don't want, or missing things you do (e.g. a `Person` might eventually have an `Address` or some other object that will also need cloning).

Comment: OK for Old School clone(). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`[].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
Persons.prototype.clone = function() {
   var clone = new Persons();
   clone.mItems = this.mItems.map(function(person) {
     return Object.assign(new Person, person);
   });
   return clone;
};
```